# How to add some text between the author names and their affiliations?

Tags: author, affiliation

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author[1]{AuthorA}
\author[1*]{AuthorB}
\affil[1]{Institute Name}
\affil[*]{Address correspondence to: AuthorB@gmail.com}
\maketitle
\date{}
\begin{abstract}
QWERTYUIOP
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: Output of the code]

What is want is to add a line "On behalf of the XYZ collaboration" between the "AuthorA and AuthorB" line and the "Institute Name" line. Can you please help?

Comment: The easy solution is to **not** use `\maketitle`.  It is mostly implemented as a tabular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the source code since `authblk` has changed the definition of `\@author`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@author{\ifx\AB@affillist\AB@empty\AB@author\else
      \ifnum\value{affil}>\value{Maxaffil}\def\rlap##1{##1}%
    \AB@authlist\\[\affilsep]\behalf\\\AB@affillist
    \else  \AB@authors\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\def\behalf{On behalf of the XYZ collaboration}
\author[1]{AuthorA}
\author[1*]{AuthorB}
\affil[1]{Institute Name}
\affil[*]{Address correspondence to: AuthorB@gmail.com}
\maketitle
\date{}
\begin{abstract}
QWERTYUIOP
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]